# msi Radio button text is not showing completely, how to fix that?

Tags: installation, msi

Radio button text is not showing completely.In the final install screen it is showing with characters truncated.
If you observe, the last words are truncated as in below screen.

[image: screen1]

But in the dialogs section of installshield, it is showing correctly.Even the logo from rtf file also missing in the above screen but showing in below screen.

[image: screen2]

Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: This may be due to the display has a custom scale factor.

Comment: can you suggest what need to be updated to fix this in msi, even the logo also not visible